# Fabric get task attributes

Tags: python, fabric

I defined a fabric def using decorators like below:

```
@task(alias=dp)
def deploy:
    # the code
```

But I want to have access to the alias inside my def?

I can't use self. to get access :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can do it in direct way, but if you will call task trough the 'task api' - kind of wrapper - you will have access to the parameters, at least inside the 'itnernaltask'.

```
from fabric.api import execute, task
@task
def internaltask():
    execute("deploy", alias=dp)
```

Comment: I accept your response "it's not possible". Finally I just unwrap def and use class without decorator. Thus I have the inheritance of the Task class and I can accept to *args & **kwargs that contains all I need.